# CouchDB replicate not working about deleted document on target device

Tags: couchdb

I want to setup one-way replicate system.
like a backup system.

but in below senario, specific documents are not replicated to target.

1. setup replicate only device A to B. (A -> B one-way)
2. some documents will be replicated from A to B.
3. remove replicator document on B. (A !-> B)
4. remove some replicated documents on B.
5. resetup replicate device A to B. (A -> B one-way)
6. documents that deleted on B at 4. are not re-replicated from A to B.

I tried to _purge on device B, but result is same.

Is ther any way to resolve it?

I want to replicate force device A -> B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of replicating changes with CouchDB. If you delete the document on B, it will not get re-replicated from A because the deletion that occurred on B is the more recent change.

So if you replicated from B to A instead, the document would be deleted on A. If you wanted to „resolve“ this, you'd need to write your own logic, e.g.:

- back up all documents in A that have been deleted on B since the last replication
- replicate from B to A
- re-create the documents on A
- replicate from A to B

`_purge` does not reset the [changes feed](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/changes.html), which is the source of information for which documents should be replicated.